# Как работает condition_variable.wait()

Tags: c++, многопоточность, c++11, concurrency

В частности интересует выполняется ли ожидание если предикат на момент выполнения этой строки уже равен *true*

```
cond_v.wait(ul, [] { return finished_del; }); // почему это работает??
```

или эта строка тогда автоматом проскакивается без всякого ожидания.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Перегрузка `condition_variable::wait(lock, pred)` эквивалентна

```
while (!pred()) {
    cond_var.wait(lock);
}
```

Соответственно если предикат сразу же возвращает `true`, то ожидания не происходит.

Comment: А что будет если использовать wait без предиката?